# Tikzfeynman in beamer frame not where I want

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

[image]As you can see in the immage I attached, the code produces the diagram correctly, yet not where I'd like it to be, i.e. below the first line of text (the second line was just a test)

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Involved Feynman diagrams}

  At LO in $\alpha$ there is only one diagram: 
  
  \begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
        i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2  [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
        a -- [photon] b,
        f1 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2  [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)],      
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

  prova
    
\end{frame}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: possibly useful information, compiling with lualatex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Originally, I didn't enclose it in a figure environment, and I had the exact same problem. That's why I tried with figure.

Comment: Also remove `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`. `\feynmandiagram` is already a tikzpicture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `tikzpicture` environment. The command `feynmandiagram` already includes `tikzpicture`. From the docs:

> Feynman diagrams can be declared with the \feynmandiagram command. It
> is analogous to the \tikz command from TikZ and requires a final
> semi-colon (;) to finish the environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Involved Feynman diagrams}

  At LO in $\alpha$ there is only one diagram: 
  \begin{center}
      \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
        i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2  [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
        a -- [photon] b,
        f1 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2  [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)],      
      };
  \end{center}
  prova
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, this solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: `figure` environment doesn't harm and is not cause of OP problem, it only has similar effect as `center` environment -- center the Feynman diagram ( +1 )

Comment: @Zarko Sure, but why introduce a float and tie it to the spot? In presentations, captions also don't make much sense, since everyone can see that it's a figure, and numbering figures and referencing them later doesn't make much sense in a presentation (the audience neither remembers the figure nor can skip back).

Comment: `figure` in beamer not float. It is always where is inserted, so use of its positioning option, for example  `[!h]` as OP do, is nosens.  It for sure not cause OP problems but nesting of `tikzpicture`s, as you clearly stated.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the explanation, never used `figure` in `beamer`, but it makes sense ...